# How can I create chooser Intent to choose from gmail app, yahoo mail app or browser?

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, yahoo-mail

I tried to search on Google but didn't find an appropriate answer.

I want to click a `TextView` and it will show a dialog that allows the user to  choose optional email.
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intet = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intet.setType("message/rfc822");
                intet.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                startActivity(intet);
```

This will open up a dialog that contains a list of apps installed on the device that can send an email.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yes, that's cool. But I just wanna open email to verify user, don't need to compose or send email.

Comment: So you can remove the line where text is being supplied to the app.

Comment: Thank you ! Have a nice day

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to use the following, it will only open the applications that provide mail facility and not all apps that can share data.

`Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "subject" + "&body=" + "body" + "&to=" + email_id);
emailIntent.setData(data);
startActivity(emailIntent);`

`"subject"` is the subject of mail, `"body"` is the content of the mail, and `"email_id"` is the id of the receiver of the mail.

You can keep the subject , body and email_id empty if you want the user to fill in the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

for open gmail app
try this code:

```
Intent gmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
gmail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
startActivity(gmail);
```

Comment: I think this is a old piece of code, and crashed my app !!

Comment: I meant it's include createChooser gmail app, yahoo app.